# DNS wildcard entry not working

Tags: networking, dns, wildcards

The following environment is given (of course the ip and the domain name are fake):

- domain example.com
- a-record example.com resolves to `1.1.1.1`
- wildcard entry in public dns for that domain is in place for ip `1.1.1.1`

Now my issue is that when I try to resolve foo.example.com it does not work – I would expect it resolving to `1.1.1.1` though.

Any hints on what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: You haven't provided enough information for someone to try and diagnose this. If you have an a-record wildcard entry of *.example.com -> 1.1.1.1, it should work but may be contingent on how you set it up or what provider/software you're using.

Comment: I agr with @will.beninger - we need to see the full zone file.  If you have a CNAME for example.com that will be the cause of your problem.

Comment: You both are so right (see my answer below)... Sorry for bothering and thanks for trying to help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the wildcard dns entry was not correct – unfortunately I don't have control over the zone myself and was told before that the entry is in place.
After the responsible person contacted the dns provider to have it fixed, everything now works as it should.